# Excel js api large Data

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I am currently working on an Excel web Add-in where I am making an ajax call which sometimes returning a very large amount of data.  After the data is returned I am iterating thought the data and loading values to cells in one sync.  If the returned data is big enough it would crash the add-in.  I have tried loading the data to the cells in batches, meaning for every 500 rows I tried to sync and then continue loading data into cells, but after loading the first 500 rows instead of continuing after the sync it exits out of the loop.  I am new to Excel Js API and I am not sure I am doing this portion of my code correctly and I am unable to find any examples of this, any help would be appreciated.

```
    function loadExcelData() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        var WebConnectAPI = "../../Data/GetExcelData";
        $("#Info").html("")
        var app = context.workbook.application;
        app.load("calculationMode");

        return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            app.suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync();

            $.when(getExcelData(WebConnectAPI)).done(function (data) {
            LoadDataV3(data, context);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#Error").html("Error:" + textStatus);
            console.log("jqXHr:" + jqXHR + "  Status:" + textStatus + " error:" + errorThrown);
            });
        });

    }).catch (function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    $("#Error").html(error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
    });



function LoadDataV3(data, context) {

    var workSheetName = "Sheet1"; 
    var currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(workSheetName);

    if (data.data.length != 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < data.data.length; x++) {
            var y = 0
            if (x % 500 == 0 && x != 0) {
                 context.sync();
                 loadCellData(currentWorksheet, data.data, x, y);
                 }
            else {
                loadCellData(currentWorksheet, data.data, x, y);
            }
       }
        return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            $('#Export-Data').show();
          });

    }
    else {
        $("#Info").html("No data was returned for your specific search criteria.")
    }
}

    function loadCellData(currentWorksheet,excelData,x,y) {
     $.each(excelData[x], function (key, value) {

         if (x == 0) {

         var HeaderCell = currentWorksheet.getRange(tocellAddress(y + 1, x + 1));//Start on first row
         var Cell = currentWorksheet.getRange(tocellAddress(y + 1, x + 2));//Start on second row

         HeaderCell.values = [[key]];
         Cell.values = [[value]];

         HeaderCell.format.autofitColumns();
         Cell.format.autofitColumns();
         }
         else {
         var Cell = currentWorksheet.getRange(tocellAddress(y + 1, x + 2));//start on third row

         Cell.values = [[value]];
         Cell.format.autofitColumns();
         }
         y++;

     });
    }
```

Comment: You should post the code you are trying so far.

Comment: Hi here is the portion of the code where I am having issues, I am pretty sure that the syncing after hitting 500 row is not correct and I need some guidance on how to load in batches.

Comment: You've got a `return` statement executing as soon as it hits 500.

Comment: That is correct miken32, I know that is why it is currently exiting out, I should have remove that from this code I  have posted, I have tried difference variations of calling the context.sync(), with the same results, the 500 rows are loaded, but it never continues after calling a sync.  I have removed the return.

Comment: context.sync sends queued commands to the Excel document. But the only queued commands before your first context sync assign variables. You shouldn't need to sync these commands more than once. Can you show the loadCellData method so we can see what Office.js commands are being queued in it? Also, context.sync is asynchronous and your code does not await the first context.sync, nor does it chain the following line inside a .then(), so the following line starts executing before the context.sync completes.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have posted all relevant code, I understand what your saying about about my code not awaiting the first context.sync, nor does it chain the following line inside .then(), I was attempting to fix the issue I am having when trying to load  a very large amount of data and go held up trying to load and sync data with in the loop instead of loading all the data at once and then syncing, in trying to do that I know I have tried some very erroneous code that goes again the principles and I just stop there.  Is the way I am going about it correct and if so what is the correct method.

Comment: Problem solved, I realized that I was going around this issue the wrong way and have since updated my code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took in my above code was not correct due to my misunderstanding of how the context.sync actually worked, as mentioned in the js api documentation you should really just need one context sync. For loading large amounts of data the data should be queued up in chunks of ranges and then sync once all data is queued.

Comment: Hi @ottalese, are you loading external data? if so, can you share the entire code on how you did it? i am trying to pull in Salesforce report or objects data into Excel using JS, but don't know how to do it. Kindly help.